# Sencha app build native issue with cordova

Tags: php, android, extjs, cordova

Having issues with a Cordova enabled Sencha Touch 2.3.1 app.  All works fine in the browser. When I do "sencha app build native" sencha compiles the apk without error.  But when I run on the device and test with chrome://inspect my list view isn't populating.

Code for the store:

```
Ext.define('PlatinumApp.store.PlatinumStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'PlatinumApp.model.PlatinumModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'PlatinumApp.model.PlatinumModel',
    storeId: 'PlatinumStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'app/extra/PlatinumStore.php'
    }
}
});
```

List works fine in a browser on the desktop. But when run on device I get the following in console:

GET file:///android_asset/www/app/extra/PlatinumStore.php undefined         app/extra/PlatinumStore.php:1

I'm assuming that Sencha isn't copying the extra .php file/folder to the cordova build but can't find anything on the google machine that tells me how to resolve.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a web accessible url for your store.  Cordova doesn't know how to run PHP, but your web server does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include any file which isn't part of (1) the Sencha theme, or (2) your Sencha JS application (bundled together into the single JS file), then you need to add it in your *app.json* under "resources".

Having said that, can PHP files even run locally on Android?